# Unity 5 Closing Menu On Multiple GameObjects When A New Menu is Opened?

Tags: unity, c#

I am trying to make a menu system for each GameObject, and when a GameObject is clicked it will close all other menus and open the one for that GameObject. I am using one script for this:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class BlockMenus : MonoBehaviour 
{   
Vector3 point;

public Transform block;
public GameObject activeBlock;

bool buttonActive = false;
bool activeBlockActive = false;

string hitObject = "";

void Update()
{
    point = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(block.position);
}

void OnMouseDown()
{
    hitObject = this.gameObject.transform.tag;

    buttonActive = !buttonActive;
    activeBlockActive = !activeBlockActive;

    activeBlock.SetActive(activeBlockActive);
}

void OnGUI()
{
    if(buttonActive)
    {
        switch(hitObject)
        {
            case "mine":
                GUI.Box(new Rect(((point.x) * (1.08f)), ((Screen.height - point.y) * (0.1f)), (Screen.width * (0.3f)), (Screen.height * (0.5f))), "");
                GUI.Button(new Rect(((point.x) * (1.08f)), ((Screen.height - point.y) * (0.87f)), (Screen.width * (0.05f)), (Screen.height * (0.06f))), "Build Mine");
                break;
        }
    }   
}
}
```

Comment: What is your goal? What is your exact question/problem?

Comment: I want to make the script close every other GUI except for the one that was just opened. But I cannot figure out how to do so.

Comment: What do you mean by every other GUI? The inspector gui or some third party one? Do you have an example?

Comment: By GUI I mean everything in the OnGUI() method

Comment: Few things. You should set your bools = to true instead of !themselves, it will help you comprehend what you're doing. If you are using a canvas, and all your GUI Objects are on the same canvas, setActive will turn them all on or off.

Comment: I am not using the Canvas, I am using:
GUI.Box(new Rect(((point.x) * (1.08f)), ((Screen.height - point.y) * (0.1f)), (Screen.width * (0.3f)), (Screen.height * (0.5f))), "");
-

Comment: Why are you using the old gui system if this is unity5?

Comment: Unity old-style gui is obsolete, I would highly recommend not to use it, and not waste your time on investigation

Answer (score 0):

This may work/help. The best [solution](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/31789/how-to-hide-gui-box-once-clicked.html) I can muster/find is toggling the GUI objects individually and not just setting them all at once. You don't need to do it in a switch really. This is a mix of your code and the solution I found.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class BlockMenus : MonoBehaviour 
{   
    Vector3 point;

    public Transform block;
    public GameObject activeBlock;

    bool buttonActive = true; 
    bool activeBlock = false; 

void Update()
{
    point = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(block.position);
}

void OnMouseDown()
{
    buttonActive = !buttonActive; /* Turn button off */
    activeBlock = !activeBlock; /* Turn block on */
}

void OnGUI()
{
    if(buttonActive) /* Button is live */
    {
       GUI.Button("Button"); /* Put button specs in */
    }   
    if(activeBlock){ /* Block is live */
       GUI.Box("Box"); /* Put box specs in */
    }
}
}
```

Also I realized the need to use the !. Makes sense if you are only using the mouseDown. Alternatively you could add an opposite mouseUp to swap things back, but both should do relatively the same thing. Although if you use the mouseUp you may end up with a very fast switch every time you click.